TV Series about kids/teen becoming heroes with the aid of a magic pencil
A group of Kids or Teenagers (unsure which they were as i was a kid back then (1990's) everyone older than me always looked the same) enter this abandoned house. inside they find all these different people/creatures who are all friendly and i think they were in hiding from  the badguys.
For some reason or another the Teenagers decide to fight the badguys and one of the people in the house has this pencil and draws them hero suits, weapons and mecha to fight with.
at one point they are trying to collect these coins and i remember for some reason or another one of the coins are lost (destroy, unobtainable, not sure) but they work out they could create a new one by drawing it with the pencil. i think also the pencil is almost a Deus Ex Machina as after exhausting every known option they turn to it and draw something new to help solve a crisis and i think the bad guys are after it to.
I am reminded of Power Rangers but the hero suits in this series looked cooler. i'm quite sure the series aired on Agro's Cartoon Connection on Prime Seven in Australia as at the time that was where i got all my cartoons from
Edit: it was live action

This sounds like Beetleborgs, a Power-Rangers-like show from 1996: Three kids enter a haunted house on a dare and meet a genie called Flabber that looks like Jay Leno who grants their wish and turns them into their favorite comic book superheroes, the Beetleborgs. They later meet the comic book's creator, who  draws them new weapons and armor that come true with Flabber's help. The Beetleborgs were also looking for 8 Astral Coins in order to reunite them with a powerful sword.
Here's the intro:




Was it Ghostwriter? the kids used pencils a lot I think.
http://pencilcasebook.blogspot.com/2009/05/ghostwriter-whats-up-with-alex.html

edited my question however this should have really been a comment than an answer

I've always assumed that it was implied that answers were the best to start. Since, users do not initially have enough reputation to make comments.

at 50 Rep, on both Beta Sites and Graduated Sites, and can be raised as a flag by anyone with 15 Rep

Oh. Thanks for the info.  I guess I made that all up. :-/

No it's wasn't Ghostwriter as 1. i do remember that series but only like about 2 arcs and 2. Ghostwriter aired on ABC, most times it was on after 9 AM as i only saw it when i was sick from school (which i only saw "Attack of the Slime Monster" and some arc about a young girl who i think was a hacker and Ghostwriter was traveling though the internet/cyberspace to get to her), this show i saw on Seven i watched faithfully every morning for 2 reasons, firstly i was waiting for the return of Sailor Moon, secondly was because i liked it
